# C#, как сохранить в файл разнородные данные

Tags: c#

C#. Подскажите, как сохранить в файл разнородные данные, если конкретнее, нужно сохранить, а потом считать из файла несколько дабл переменных и дабл массив? Проблема в том, что очередность записи в файл переменных неизвестна.

Comment: Почему тогда не записывать в БД, sqllite например?

Comment: А чем вам не угодила стандартная сериализация?

Comment: Может быть, подойдет база данных ключ-значение [Berkeley DB](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_DB). Добавлю, что нужно использовать какую-то старую версию, поскольку сейчас Oracle дотянул эту базу до мощной системы с транзакциями и репликацией и даже натянул на нее SQLite. Это все, конечно, избыточно для вашей задачи.

Comment: вам сохранять в каком виде надо? бинарном или текстовый тоже подойдет?

Answer (score 2):

Если вы можете определить какую-то структуру, согласно которой нужно организовать данные, которые нужно хранить в файле, то можно использовать `XmlSerializer`.
Пример кода:

```
// запись даных в объект
var dataInstance = new MyData();
dataInstance.DoubleValue1 = 0.1;
dataInstance.DoubleValue2 = 0.2;
dataInstance.DoubleList.Add(0.3);
dataInstance.DoubleList.Add(0.4);

// сохранение в файл
using (var stream = new FileStream(@"c:\data\data.xml", FileMode.Create))
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyData));
    serializer.Serialize(stream, dataInstance);
}

// чтение из файла
MyData data;

using (var stream = new FileStream(@"c:\data\data.xml", FileMode.Open))            
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyData));
    data = serializer.Deserialize(stream) as MyData;
}

Console.WriteLine(data.DoubleValue1);
Console.WriteLine(data.DoubleValue2);
Console.WriteLine(data.DoubleList[1]);
```

И, собственно, сам класс с данными:

```
// Класс, инкапсулирующий данные
public class MyData
{
    public Double DoubleValue1 { get; set; }
    public Double DoubleValue2 { get; set; }
    public List<Double> DoubleList { get; set; }
    public MyData()
    {
        this.DoubleList = new List<Double>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Вот, похоже. Можно ли создать структуру с переменными и массивом, у меня в лоб не получилось?

Comment: Всё отлично, большое спасибо klutch1991! То, что нужно! Я раньше не мог создать структуру с массивом на борту, теперь благодаря Вам понял как это делать.

Answer (score 1):

Если очерёдность данных не известна, то простых решений нет, придётся придумывать какой-то механизм сериализации/десериализации, например сохранять вместе с данными дополнительную информацию о типе и размере (для массивов), а потом при чтении аккуратно всё это разбирать. Что-то типа такого:

```
type (1 байт)
size (4 байта)
data (размер из поля size)
-----
type (1 байт)
size (4 байта)
data (размер из поля size)
-----
 ...
```

Comment: для массивов еще и количество измерений бы не помешало, но в общем не надо изобретать велосипед, стандартные сериализаторы достаточно оптимизированы для этих задач.

Comment: Согласен, что изобретать свой механизм сериализации нужно в последнюю очередь, просто желание произвольной очерёдности записи/чтения может накладывать свои ограничения на стандартные механизмы. Честно говоря, я сам не очень понимаю, где может понадобиться запись данных в файл, если порядок записи не известен, их же потом при чтении правильно по переменным не раскидаешь.

Comment: @Nikita я тоже хорошо думал про стандартные сериализаторы пока не пришлось сериализовать DataSet. В общем теперь сначала проверяю, потом использую.

Comment: в общем случае десериалиация данных из файла с неизвестной структурой невозможна, а если структура известна, то можно и без дополнительных данных справиться. Для случаев с произвольным порядком записи кроме XML или JSON особо ни чего не придумаешь, но это текст.